# Shared CSS file blazor

Tags: c#, css, blazor

I have 2 pages in my Blazor app working:

**Login.razor** in the *Auth* folder

**AddPerson.razor** in the *Profile* folder

Now I have a CSS file working for the AddPerson.razor file.

My question is how can I work with the same CSS file for both pages?

[image: File structures]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strengths of the new .NET5 CSS isolation feature (placing a css file "below" your razor file), is that the css is NOT shared between pages/components making them easier to develop and contained/bundled to the specific component.

If you however want to add some shared css that would be available thru out your app, you would do it "the old fashion way" by editing the site-wide css file. Using the Blazor templates, that would be `wwwroot/css/site.css` for server side or `wwwroot/css/app.css` for client side.

Answer (score 2):

Late alternative answer sorry. I have the "Web Compiler" extension installed. You can create a .scss file that imports another handy for definitions etc.

[image]

`MessageView.razor.scss`

```
@import "common.scss";

.bubble {
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: $bubbleShadow; 
...
```